# xslt transforma los caracteres utf-8 a una codificación diferente

Tags: xml, utf-8, xsl, xslt

Estoy transformando un un xsl a partir de un XML con codificación UTF-8 pero cuando lo transformo me sale los caracteres con otra codificación.

**Este el documento .xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="no"  />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        
    <xsl:text>USE centre; &#xa; </xsl:text>
    
        <xsl:for-each select="ins/cicles/familia">
        
        <xsl:text> INSERT INTO cicles (id, nom, simbol, grau, familia)&#xa; VALUES(</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>'<xsl:value-of select="cicle/@id" /></xsl:text><xsl:text>',</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>'<xsl:value-of select="cicle" /></xsl:text><xsl:text>',</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>'<xsl:value-of select="cicle/@grau" /></xsl:text> <xsl:text>',</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>'<xsl:value-of select="cicle" /></xsl:text> <xsl:text>',</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>'<xsl:value-of select="@nom" /></xsl:text> <xsl:text>');&#xa;</xsl:text>
        
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Este el documento .XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ins nom="Instituto">
    <cicles>
        <familia nom="Informàtica">
            <cicle id="ASIX" grau="Superior">Administració de Sistemes Informàtics i Xarxes</cicle>
            <cicle id="SMX" grau="Mig">Sistemes Microinformàtics i Xarxes</cicle>
        </familia>
        <familia nom="Administratiu">
            <cicle id="GA" grau="Mig">Gestió Administrativa</cicle>
            <cicle id="AF" grau="Superior">Administració i Finances</cicle>
        </familia>
    </cicles>
```

Este es un resultado obtenido con la transformación:

```
VALUES('ASIX','AdministraciÃ³ de Sistemes InformÃ tics i Xarxes','Superior','AdministraciÃ³ de Sistemes InformÃ tics i Xarxes','InformÃ tica');
```

Comment: ¿Qué software utilizas para ejecutar el programa XSLT? Lo utilizas con un API?

Comment: Utilizo un IDE, en concreto eclipse

Comment: Creo que tanto tu XML y tu XSLT están bien y el resultado debería ser un documento de formato `text` con la codificación UTF-8.  En tu IDE, Eclipse, ¿funciona bien transformar al formato `html` o `xml` con UTF-8 y ver los resultados? Tal vez, cuando ves documentos de formato texto Eclipse utilice una codificación 8 bit como Windows 1252 o ISO-8859, de esa manera se mira dos caracteres en lugar de uno para cualquier carácter non ASCII como `à`. ¿Has tratado de cambiar la configuración de Eclipse para ver documentos de formato texto con otra codificación?